# Does FAA class 1 medical require binocular vision?

Tags: faa, medical

Can I get an FAA Class 1 medical if I don't have binocular vision?

I live in Italy and for EASA I can't get my first class medical certificate to be a pilot.  But can I get at least FAA 1 class to be a pilot in USA?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, with a special issuance, [and provided you meet the criteria here](https://www.faa.gov/ame_guide/app_process/exam_tech/et/31-34/mv) you can get an FAA class 1 medical with monocular vision.

> An applicant will be considered monocular when there is only one eye
> or when the best corrected distant visual acuity in the poorer eye is
> no better than 20/200. An individual with one eye, or effective visual
> acuity equivalent to monocular, **may be considered for medical
> certification, any class, through the special issuance section of part
> 67** (14 CFR 67.401).